# Initialize i18next in Azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have an azure http trigger function, which is called by a client with some data and client's culture string e.g. "en-US". index.js handles the azure request. myWorker.js has a function doStuff() which prepares data to return to the client. I am using i18next for localizations.

index.js needs to pass the culture string to i18next. It seems logical to put i18next in myWorker.js but it needs to load before index.js calls the doStuff function. Forgive me if this is a mess but I'm new to node and don't know the best way to set it up.

How does index.js pass the culture string to myworker.js, wait for i18next to load, pass the main data to dostuff() and finish with context.done()?

```
index.js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    switch (req.body.data.action) {
        case 'doWork':
            let myworker = require('./myWorker')(req.body.data.culture)  //culture string for i18next
            let retval = myworker.dostuff();  //i18next fails as it isn't loaded yet.
            context.res = {
                status: 200, body: {someData: retval}
            };
            break;
        case 'anotherCommand':
        ....
    }
    context.done();
}

myWorker.js
let i18next = require("i18next");
let backend = require("i18next-node-fs-backend");

function dostuff() {
     calc some stuff using i18next.t(key);
}

function setup_i18next(cultr) {
    i18next
        .use(backend)
        .init({
            fallbackLng: 'en',
            lng: cultr,
            backend: {
                loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
            },
            ns: ['myspace1', 'myspace2']
        })
        .then(function (t) {
            ????
         });
}

module.exports = function(cultre) {
    setup_i18next(cultre);
    return {
        dostuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fs-backend, like this:

```
// i18n.js
const { join } = require('path')
const { readdirSync, lstatSync } = require('fs')
const i18next = require('i18next')
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend')
i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .init({
    // debug: true,
    initImmediate: false, // setting initImediate to false, will load the resources synchronously
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en',
    preload: readdirSync(join(__dirname, '../locales')).filter((fileName) => {
      const joinedPath = join(join(__dirname, '../locales'), fileName)
      const isDirectory = lstatSync(joinedPath).isDirectory()
      return isDirectory
    }),
    ns: 'backend-app',
    defaultNS: 'backend-app',
    backend: {
      loadPath: join(__dirname, '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json')
    }
  })
module.exports = (lng) => i18next.getFixedT(lng || 'en')
```

Then just use it like this:

```
const t = require('../i18n')(lng)
const title = t('invitation.subject')
```

Comment: Hello, that's got it working - thank you! But a question. With debug on, before I get to `t("invitation.subject')` I get "something IS WRONG with your application". getFixedT should set my language, so I'm not sure why it says languages are undefined. It works so no big deal...

Comment: sorry, there was a missing piece.... you need to set the lng option to prevent this (updated the sample above)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @adrai's answer (which I never would have figured out) I think it can be tweaked to specify the language in the init. Otherwise, we'd unnecessarily load the 'en' translations if another language is specified via lang.

```
const { join } = require('path')
const { readdirSync, lstatSync } = require('fs')
const i18next = require('i18next')
const SyncBackend = require('i18next-sync-fs-backend')

module.exports = (lang) => {
  i18next
  .use(SyncBackend)
  .init({
    // debug: true,
    initImmediate: false,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng:lang,
    preload: readdirSync(join(__dirname, '../locales')).filter((fileName) => {
      const joinedPath = join(join(__dirname, '../locales'), fileName)
      const isDirectory = lstatSync(joinedPath).isDirectory()
      return isDirectory
    }),
    ns: ['k2locals','sfaDebugger'],
    defaultNS: 'k2locals',
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      loadPath: join(__dirname, '../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json')
    }
  })
  return i18next.getFixedT(lang || 'en', 'k2locals')
}
```

Comment: this would init i18next on each function call... just set the lng prop like suggested in my last comment (above)